# i want to enable the pod to pod communication in different namespace same cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I have kubernetes cluster with 1 master 1 worker , i have DB service postgres running one namespace "PG" and i have another service config-server running in default namespace and i am unable to access postgres from config-server service which is in default namespace

Kubernetes version 1.13 
overlay network -calico
 as per the articles i read if pods doesnt have any network policy defined then pods can be reached to any other namespace pod without any restriction , need help in how to achieve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using kubernetes cluster with overlay network as calico , if there is no network policy created , by default kubernetes core dns will resolve the service but we have to add the . in the application or env variable where you are calling the service in another namespace. That will allow cross namespace communication

Comment: If this solution worked for you please mark it as approved. It will help community n the future. You may also consider adding example of yaml file to your answer.

Comment: What do you mean by add the .?

Comment: Namespace.application-variable

Answer (score 0):

should be able to reach any pod from another pod on the same cluster.
one quick way to check is to ping the service dns of the pod from another pod

get into config service pod and try to run the below command

```
ping <postgres-service-name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local
```

you should be able to get ping response

Comment: ping postgres.pg.svc.cluster.local didnt work as pod was trying to connect postgres and failing

Comment: no network policy is defined , also i tried with network policy to allow all traffic from all namespaces , even then didnt resolve